# Remove focus from textbox when iscroll region is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, onblur, iscroll4

I have defined some events when input textbox has got focus and some task to perform when focus is removed. I am also using iscroll4 but textbox is out of the scroller. My problem is when textbox gets focus and i click on the iscroll area the foucs from textbox is not going. But if i click on area outside iscroll the foucs is removing from the textbox. I am not understand why clicking on the iscroll region does not remove the focus whereas click events work. I have defined the `blur` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using `iscroll4` and in the `iscroll.js` file there is the following event defined :

```
onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
}
```

I commented the `e.preventDefault` line and it worked for me. This was basically preventing the `blur` event to fire when i clicked on the iscroll region because this is the first event that iscroll fires when it receives any mouse down event.